# Problem with meizu pro 5

Tags: ubuntu-touch, smartphone, meizu-mx4

I upgraded my Meizu pro 5 to Ubuntu Touch 16.04, but now I cannot roll back to the stable version 15.04. Even with the developer mode enabled the phone isn't recognized by my computer.

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't recognized by my computer"? Can you reach it over adb?

Comment: Is Ubuntu Touch 16.04 not stable on the Pro 5?

Comment: Yes it's 16.04 staging channel, i cannot reach the phone via adb.

Comment: That's bad. But i hear Meizu has great customer support (or was that BQ?), maybe you can reach someone there

Comment: From what i have heard in the past it is BQ that have the good customer service and Meizu does not.

Comment: May you could try to enter the bootloader and then I guess you can reflash by using the fast-boot option.